# Why does Android Studio auto-download Gradle when I build my project?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

When I import a project to Android Studio, it auto-downloads the Gradle zip. Is there a way to build my project without having to download the file?

[image]

Comment: I don't know what you mean to say. But if you are interested to use a library without compiling it in your gradle then at first you have to get that library's jar file and then add the file to your project. Pardon me if I misunderstand your problem

Comment: sorry,  i found download the file is necessary, because the download speed to slow , i can't stand. project compile success when completed download, thank you answer!   the project download from github need download a lot of dependencies

Answer (score 4):

You can set your android studio to work offline so that it doesnt have to download anything. Go:

> File -> Settings -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Offline work

[image]

Also set the Command line options to `--offline` in your Compiler options:

[image]

Comment: i was also experiencing the same. Everytime i created new project, the Android Studio keeps downloading new Gradle.zip file... and it's quite big. 138.58mb for Gradle 6.1.1.all.zip For all users that has internet connectivity problems, this is a real matter.